# React native TouchableHighlight on press open another screen

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

iam new in react native and start my first project , i have a login screen and when i press into `TouchableHighlight` i need to open another screen , but the problem is i failed to make the function that move from login to second screen , this is my code

**Login.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text,SecureView ,Button,Image,TextInput,StyleSheet,View,NavigatorIOS,TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
require('./HygexListView.js');

class LoginView extends Component {
   constructor(props){
    super(props);


  }
  onPositive(){
    this.props.navigator.pop()

  };


    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>
                    HYGEX
                </Text>
                <View>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Username"
                        style={styles.formInput}
                         />
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Password"
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                        style={styles.formInput1}
                         />

                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                onPress={ () => this.onPositive() }>
               <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
               </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
    onPress()  {
  this.props.navigator.push({
     title: "HygexListView",
     component: HygexListView,
  });

}
}
```

and when press into TouchableHighlight i need to open this screen

**HygexListView.js**

```
    'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, ListView, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class HygexListView extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
        'John', 'Joel', 'James', 'Jimmy', 'Jackson', 'Jillian', 'Julie', 'Devin'
      ])
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 22}}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
module.exports = HygexListView;
```

Comment: Where have you included in the Navigator component?

Comment: @agent_hunt i dont know how to do this , !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open another screen react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692005/open-another-screen-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

From what i see there, i *think* you forgot to use/setup the Navigator component. Try to organize it this way:

**Your components**

```
    class HygexListView extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.state = {
          dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
            'John', 'Joel', 'James', 'Jimmy', 'Jackson', 'Jillian', 'Julie', 'Devin'
          ])
        };
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <Navigator
              renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
              navigator={this.props.navigator}
              navigationBar={
                <Navigator.NavigationBar style={{backgroundColor: 'red', alignItems: 'center'}}
                    routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper} />
              } />
        );
      }

      renderScene(route, navigator) {
        return (
          <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 22}}>
            <ListView
              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
              renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    module.exports = HygexListView;
```

**index.ios.js**

```
    class yourApp extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Navigator
              initialRoute={{id: 'Login'}}
              renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
              configureScene={(route) => {
                if (route.sceneConfig) {
                  return route.sceneConfig;
                }
                return Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight;
              }} />
        );
      }
      renderScene(route, navigator) {
        switch (route.id) {
          case 'HygexListView':
            return (
              <HygexListView navigator={navigator} />
            );
          case 'Login':
            return (
              <Login navigator={navigator} />
            );
          default:
            return null;   
        }
      }
    }
```

basically what you do, instead of rendering your component, you render your navigator that using renderScene() renders your component/view.

the approach to use the index file as an organizer of the views, is just a preference of mine. but you will see there, that when an "id" is passed to the navigator, the scene will be rendered using the component that matches the id on the switch case.

Comment: i need when click into TouchableHighlight open HygexListView !! just