# Open another screen in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I have this screen in react native

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { AppRegistry,TouchableOpacity, Text ,Button,Image,TextInput,PropTypes,StyleSheet,View,NavigatorIOS,TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';


    class LoginView extends Component {

        render() {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>
                        HYGEX
                    </Text>
                    <View>
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder="Username"
                            style={styles.formInput}
                             />
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder="Password"
                            secureTextEntry={true}
                            style={styles.formInput1}
                             />

                    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                    onPress={() => this.move()}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
                   </TouchableHighlight>

                    </View>
                </View>
            );
        }

      move() {
      //what i can do here to go to Socrce screen ???
        }
      }
```

Something like login screen, now when I click into `TouchableHighlight`
    I need to open this screen

```
    'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, ListView, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class HygexListView extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
        'John', 'Joel', 'James', 'Jimmy', 'Jackson', 'Jillian', 'Julie', 'Devin'
      ])
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 22}}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
module.exports = HygexListView;
```

I tried to implement move method but I failed! Any idea why?

Does react-native have a method to change the screen when click into  `TouchableHighlight`?

Answer (score 3):

As others pointed out, you have to use an instance of `Navigator` to transition between screens. Maybe you can have a look at the [example apps](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/) in the React Native repo. I also find [this router package](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) quite easy to set up, and it also includes an example app that you can use as a starting point.

**Edit**
As a simple example using react-native-router-flux, you can edit the `Example.js` file in the `Example` directory to look like this:

```
import React, {
  Component,
} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import LoginView from './LoginView';
import HygexListView from './HygexListView';
import {
  Scene,
  Router,
  Actions,
} from 'react-native-router-flux';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'transparent', justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  tabBarStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
  },
  tabBarSelectedItemStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
  },
});


// define this based on the styles/dimensions you use
const getSceneStyle = (/* NavigationSceneRendererProps */ props, computedProps) => {
  const style = {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    shadowColor: null,
    shadowOffset: null,
    shadowOpacity: null,
    shadowRadius: null,
  };
  if (computedProps.isActive) {
    style.marginTop = computedProps.hideNavBar ? 0 : 64;
    style.marginBottom = computedProps.hideTabBar ? 0 : 50;
  }
  return style;
};

class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router getSceneStyle={getSceneStyle}>
        <Scene key="login" component={LoginView} initial={true}/>
        <Scene key="hygex" component={HygexListView } />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

Then, in your component's `move` function, you have to do the following:

```
move(){
    Actions.hygex(); // This will perform a slide transition, but you can customize it. Have a look at the docs for that.
```

I have not tested the code, so there might be some typos/missing imports/code, but it should give you an idea of what you have to do.
    }

Comment: There you go. That should get you up and running.

Comment: thank you @martinarroyo, when i run the application i got this error , 

"undefined is not a function (evalutiongreactNativeRouterFLux.Actions.hygex()) !!

Comment: Implement [this function](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/Example/Example.js#L43) and pass it to the <Router> component as a prop like [this](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/Example/Example.js#L94)

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a Navigator, which is roughly a component that manages all stuff related to screens, and header bar with back button and etc.

As you are a beginner, I suggest you to look at the docs on this link:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html

Sorry for the short answer, I'm on my phone.

Good luck!

Comment: i tried this but i cannot do apply this for my case

Comment: i try many example and always i got error at props.this.novigator or something like this , if you know how i can implement this method please tell me coz i need this for all my project !

Answer (score 1):

```
"use strict";

var React = require("react-native");

var {
    Component,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    TouchableHighlight,
    View,
} = React;

var SecureView = require("./SecureView");

class LoginView extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: "",
            password: ""
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>
                    Sign In
                </Text>
                <View>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Username"
                        onChange={(event) => this.setState({username: event.nativeEvent.text})}
                        style={styles.formInput}
                        value={this.state.username} />
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Password"
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                        onChange={(event) => this.setState({password: event.nativeEvent.text})}
                        style={styles.formInput}
                        value={this.state.password} />
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={(this.onSubmitPressed.bind(this))} style={styles.button}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }

    onSubmitPressed() {
        this.props.navigator.push({
            title: "Secure Page",
            component: SecureView,
            passProps: {username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password},
        });
    }

};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 30,
        marginTop: 65,
        alignItems: "stretch"
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 18,
        marginBottom: 10
    },
    formInput: {
        height: 36,
        padding: 10,
        marginRight: 5,
        marginBottom: 5,
        marginTop: 5,
        flex: 1,
        fontSize: 18,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "#555555",
        borderRadius: 8,
        color: "#555555"
    },
    button: {
        height: 36,
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#555555",
        borderColor: "#555555",
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 8,
        marginTop: 10,
        justifyContent: "center"
    },
    buttonText: {
        fontSize: 18,
        color: "#ffffff",
        alignSelf: "center"
    },
});

module.exports = LoginView;
```

Comment: A few things to note about the root JavaScript file:

We are including the NavigatorIOS tag
We are requiring the LoginView class which we’ll create later. This is the first screen the user will see
We’re rendering the NavigatorIOS, giving the first screen a title, and setting the first screen as the LoginView class
We are creating a style for the navigation
With that out of the way, let’s move on to the code for the LoginView class. Create a file called LoginView.js at the root of your project and add the following code:

Comment: The props variable we are passing is for any passed variables. We’re not passing any to the LoginView, but we will be for the SecureView in a moment. The username and password variables are being initialized as blank.

This brings us to the render function. Instead of explaining everything, I’m just going to brush over the important part of this function:

Comment: <TextInput
    placeholder="Username"
    onChange={(event) => this.setState({username: event.nativeEvent.text})}
    style={styles.formInput}
    value={this.state.username} />
<TextInput
    placeholder="Password"
    secureTextEntry={true}
    onChange={(event) => this.setState({password: event.nativeEvent.text})}
    style={styles.formInput}
    value={this.state.password} />
<TouchableHighlight onPress={(this.onSubmitPressed.bind(this))} style={styles.button}>
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>

Answer (score 0):

You have to use navigator. please read the documentation as mentioned below. and if you will need then i will share you my code.

Here is an example: [NavigatorExample](https://github.com/Anuj-786/NavigatorExapple)

Comment: Hi @Bokerjy Zahgan i have created a example for in the link. In this example i have created two files in app folder for two different screens using navigator please see and you have query you can ask me. link here https://github.com/Anuj-786/NavigatorExapple